# Make a website converting text to audio [Google Cloud Text to Speech API]

Tags: google-cloud-platform, text-to-speech, google-cloud-speech, google-text-to-speech

I'm a beginner in coding. I would like to make a simple website using Google Cloud Text to Speech API.

1. a web site with a text box
2. you write a text in the text box and click a button "convert to audio"
3. you can download mp3 file which is made by google cloud text to speech api

I have read [Google Cloud Text to Speech API's official site](https://cloud.google.com/text-to-speech/docs/), but couldn't find a solution.

I have searched like "develop a website converting text to audio".
I found this site.
[Creating an HTML Application to Convert Text Files to Audio Files](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/robert_mcmurray/2015/05/27/creating-an-html-application-to-convert-text-files-to-audio-files/)
However, it didn't meet my request.

Could you give me any information to develop a website converting text to audio?

Thank you in advance.

Sincerely, Kazu

I have made a python program on Google Colaboratory. I would like to do the same thing on a website.

```
from google.colab import drive
drive.mount('/content/drive')

!cp ./drive/'My Drive'/credential.json ./credential.json
import os
os.environ["GOOGLE_APPLICATION_CREDENTIALS"]="credential.json"
f= open("text.ssml","w+")
f.write('<speak><prosody rate="slow">hello world</prosody></speak>')
f.close()
!pip install google-cloud-texttospeech
#!/usr/bin/env python
from google.cloud import texttospeech
client = texttospeech.TextToSpeechClient()
with open('text.ssml', 'r') as f:
    ssml = f.read()
    input_text = texttospeech.types.SynthesisInput(ssml=ssml)
voice = texttospeech.types.VoiceSelectionParams(language_code='en-US', name="en-US-Wavenet-A")

audio_config = texttospeech.types.AudioConfig(audio_encoding=texttospeech.enums.AudioEncoding.MP3)
response = client.synthesize_speech(input_text, voice, audio_config)
with open('output.mp3', 'wb') as out:
    out.write(response.audio_content)
    print('Audio content written to file "output.mp3"')
from google.colab import files
files.download('output.mp3')
```

Comment: Howdy.  You are likely going to find that your question will be too broad for Stackoverflow.  It almost sounds like you are asking for someone to write the application for you.  Is it your intent to learn enough programming to perform the task yourself?  Sounds like you need to be able to write a web site, get input text, call GCP Text to Speech API and stream the result as an MP3 file back to the requestors browser.  That's quite a few steps.  Have you attempted any of them?

Comment: Thank you for replying, Kolban. I have made a python program using GCP Text to Speech API on Google Colaboratory. I paste this code on my question. I would like to do the same thing on a website.

Comment: And I have never developed a dynamic website.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In order to achieve what you want, as you say you are new to coding the first thing is to research the GCP text-to-speech API. A good first step is to follow the quick start tutorial available [Using client libraries text-to-speech](https://cloud.google.com/text-to-speech/docs/quickstart-client-libraries#client-libraries-usage-python).

As for your requirements of an input box to convert the text to audio. You need to follow the general guidelines for deploying an application on GCP. 
[Serve Machine Learning Model on App Engine Flexible Environment](https://cloud.google.com/community/tutorials/appengine-serve-machine-learning-model)

so basically your steps would be to train a model and serve via an App engine deployment, or deploying an application which send requests with a json payload to the text-to-speech API. But you need to do quite a bit of reading. Hope this helps.

Comment: Thank you very much for your advice, Paddy. I choose the first way. Now I' developing the app using GCP text-to-speech API, Google App Engine Standard Environment and Flask. Thanks to people in Stackoverflow, I've almost completed my app. However, I face one problem. “dependent drop down list” does't work. If you could help me, I would appreciate. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59870600/dependent-drop-down-list-doest-work-flask-on-google-app-engine

Answer (score 0):

If you want the flexibility of handling multiple TTS (text to speech) providers (we have at least 4), and enhanced discovery of voices, you might want to look at [www.api.audio](http://www.api.audio)
Here's an example https://docs.api.audio/recipes/create-engaging-newscast